# Can someone rid me of these turbulent T4 template editors?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, tangible-t4-editor

I'm using Tangible's editor and (no offense guys) it sucks.  Its one painful step above notepad.  But its (afaik) the only game in town.

**Does anybody have any tips/tricks on creating T4 templates in a non-painful way?**

For instance, I'm thinking about creating a T4 Template that essentially turns a class defined in a solution into a template generator.  DTE, look for code that is marked with this or that attribute, run this or that method, and drop the results into a file.  At least I'd get legit intellisense out of the deal...

Comment: Hah! Nice play on the classics with that title.

Comment: Yeah, it's really annoying to get #ProVersionOnly in the intellisense where a member name should be. Such intentionally broken software basically forces me to bar myself from ever contributing a single penny to their company or anyone associated with it. As one person said: "It appears Tangible Engineering (@tangibleeng) has adopted a crack-dealer business model like other plug-in vendors. The FREE version doesn’t support all of the C# language. It does provide enough though for developers to decide if they need to to pay 99.98 USD for the PRO edition."

Answer (score 0):

[Devart just released a *free* T4 Editor for 2k8 and 2010 on the Visual Studio gallery.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a42a8538-8d6e-491b-8097-5a8a00174d37)  Looks nice!  First noticeable improvement is that the editor is fast compared to others.  Look and feel is like a normal code editor.  There is intellisense in the t4 blocks and in the t4 statement blocks (the intellisense feels a little kludgy, but its not too bad).  And the editor works with the standard find/replace tool window.  Altogether nice job. [Devart](http://www.devart.com/)!

(I am not associated with Devart in any way, and this is the first product of theirs I've used.)

Answer (score -1):

You could try Clarius’ “Visual T4 Editor Community edition”
http://www.visualt4.com/downloads.html

Comment: Clarius' editor sucks.  Sorry to be harsh, but it's not good at all.  Nagware, intellisense failures, the search/replace dialog is awful, I could go on....  Also, the T4 Toolbox is not an editor, it is designed to support T4 development.